# How do I animate UICollectionViewCells using Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am currently trying to get my cells to animate into the storyboard one at a time.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.alpha = 0
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1, 1, 1)
    })
}
```

This is the code that I am currently using. However, it only allows me to run the animation on all of the cells at once. What I would like is to have cell 1, 2, 3, and 4 to animate in that order. 
Any ideas on how I could go about this?
If there is a better way then please go tell me if there is.

Comment: What should trigger the animation?

Answer (score 2):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.alpha = 0
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(10, 1, 1, 0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 1.0*Double(indexPath.row),animations: { () -> Void in
    cell.alpha = 1

        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1, 1, 1)
    })
}
```

After adding

```
 delay: 1.0*Double(indexPath.row)
```

it solved my problem and now the view animates them in order. @Syed Faraz Haider Zaidi

Answer (score 0):

you can use repeat and autoreverse options.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
  cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 1, 1, 1)

}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How would I get this to animate each cell one after another until all are finished? Like a domino effect of them fading in until all have faded in. @Syed

Comment: if you want each cell to animate you can create animation function, and passed it your collection cell and run this code once you reach your last index in cell for row.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I have posted a comment on how I accomplished it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create some view with ordered animation and use only UIView not UICollectionView. When animation is completed u can show your real UICollectionView.